# AbstractMethodError in Rest Webservice

Tags: java, json, rest, exception

I am new in web service. I try to using `jax.ws..` web service with `jersey` and `spring`. When i try to send the request using `Chrome Post Client` or `CURL` in windows, following stack trace occur.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jersey-serlvet] in context with path [/rest] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.AnnotationIntrospector$Pair.findDeserializer(AnnotationIntrospector.java:1335)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findDeserializerFromAnnotation(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:675)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:535)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider._createDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:432)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider._createAndCache2(StdDeserializerProvider.java:341)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:321)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider.findValueDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:167)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider.findTypedValueDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:188)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:2820)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2690)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1308)
at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:419)
..............................
```

Following is the code of my example :

```
@Path("/loginPoint")
@Service
public class UserService {

@Resource(name= "commanUserService")
private CommanUserService commanUserService;

@POST
@Path("/login")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response login(LoginRequest request){
    System.out.println("Hello In web Services >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ");
    LoginResponse  response = commanUserService.getUserloginInformation(request);
    return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(response).build();
 }
}
```

LoginRequest.java file code :

```
@XmlRootElement(name="loginRequest")
public class LoginRequest {
private String userName;
private String password;

@XmlElement("userName")
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

@XmlElement("password")
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
 }
}
```

I suppose that problem is in mapping `JSON` request parameters with `LoginRequest` entity, but i am not sure.

Comment: An AbstractMethodError often indicates a version mismatch. Do you have multiple Jackson jars?  Can you open the source of that last call on the stack and see what it would be calling?

Comment: yes i have multiple `Jackson` jars in my project with different versions. but now i am confuse which dependency i need to remove ?

Comment: If you're using Maven the dependency:tree plugin sometimes helps.  The [dependencyManagement](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) section will also allow you to specify one version that will override all transitive dependencies.

Comment: Thank you @Pace you solve my major problem, thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

The issue was a mismatch between Jackson versions.

Answer (score 3):

When using jackson-core-asl dependency with jackson-mapper-asl becareful on choosing same version.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue and resolved myself. the issue was with the version compatibility between **jersy**(*jersy-json, jersy-server*) and **jackson**(*jackson-core-asl, jackson-mapper-asl*) jars.

so please use compatible versions like jersy 1.8 with jackson 1.8.1 jars.